How Do I Power An Arduino Nano Every?
I am pretty new to Arduino and I am making a project with my Uno R4 Wifi, it uses a servo and a motor to push a door closed, and when I power it with a 9v battery it barely moves the door, but when I use 9v wall power, it works very well, maybe better than the USB. But now I'm going to buy a few Nano Everys to make it wirelessly controlled, but the Every doesn't have a barrel jack, so I need to plug + to 5v and - to VIN, I think... but what battery pack should I use that can power the components with enough strength to move the door? I know a traditional 9v is usually horrible, but I was wondering if it's enough for a smaller board like the Nano Every? If not is a pack of 6 1.5 volts better?
I am using a
hobby servo (Hi-tec Hs-645 MG),
a generic dc motor with gearbox,
and a L293D for driving the motor
Thank you!

Do any of these Q+As help? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power+servo

Yeah I saw a lot of those, but they all used Arduino Unos, and I was unsure if they need more power than the Every needs.

a 9 V block battery contains six AAAA cells connected in series ... it has power to run a smoke detector, not much more ... make the 9 V battery from higher capacity cells

how could I get a higher capacity battery jsotola?

updated the comment ... a battery is just a collection of two or more cells ... there are many examples on the internet ... start doing some research

Would a 6 pack of AA batteries be better for the Nano Every?

try it ........

I just dont want to but all the stuff and then not be able to even power it

Please [edit] your question to add  the technical specification of your servo and especially your motor, optimally measure voltage and current of them. Then we'll be in a better position to answer.

Your question isn't really about how to power the Nano Every, but how to power a servo motor. Microprocessors have a much lower current requirement than motors.
Based on this I see that the HS-645MG High Torque, Metal Gear Premium Sport Servo would require 450 mA of current, even with no load, and 2.5 A at "stall" load.
Browsing for the effective internal series resistance of 9V batteries is a little tricky, but I saw one post suggesting it might be around 1 ohm.
Using Ohm's Law, if you are drawing, say, 2 amps trying to close your door, and the internal resistance is 1 ohm, then the voltage drop over that resistor will be 2V, thus there will only be 7V left to power your motor.
I suggest 6 x 1.5V batteries with a higher current capability (say, AA batteries) would be much more suitable than a tiny 9V battery. They really aren't designed to drive motors.

Would this also be enough to power a NRF24L01, a DC motor, and a H-bridge driver?
https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-H-bridge-Stepper-Controller-Arduino/dp/B00M0F243E/ref=sr_1_5?crid=249T4CXS9EL2R&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.JQyowzzZ9U-FWlJkRjfPJEtXLb66lZaL6yPgtgCjW1rkjOi8y-LnwhkdjYln896-tegrnwCt9B16a26ggE5PYFlAHidUOJNSm9W37zScgwfrz7i_YoYIIRc7j9JBuwtEr1gZGkjsLL5_IEq_ySmDSsQoc2S7xC7tL3vgJL7iCnbsulrBQPYpF4G4Rrmq6AloL_wREqVmYk5gJCP0lavIfw.lIlg0Y8JFX9uORQf7ZDydV7fUU2EobIa0_pVREpdCfM&dib_tag=se&keywords=h+bridge&qid=1725319806&sprefix=h+bridge%2Caps%2C183&sr=8-5

A lot depends on the specs of the motor. The more current it draws the bigger power supply you need. Different battery sizes and types have different capabilities.
